# Ruby RegExp that matches rest of line in comment

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to write a Ruby RegExp that will match the following:

```
# @name 'foo'
#   @name   'foo'
# @name foo
```

as `foo`.

It should essentially look for every line containing a commented-out `@name` and get the string that follows it.

Comment: And how does the code you wrote go about this, and how come it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this.

```
line.match(/^\#\s+@name\s+["']?(.*?)["']?$/)
```

See [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/eJv0NnlQOe)

Comment: This one does work! Any way to make it work with `"` as well, and not just `'`?

Answer (score 2):

The simple version is:

```
line.match(/^\s*\#\s*@name\s+(.*)/)
```

The more complicated version would account for `'`:

```
line.match(/^\s*\#\s*@name\s+\'?([^']*?)\'?/)
```

This doesn't account for escaped characters like `'foo\'s'`.

Comment: This is close but matches the beginning of whatever line follows as well. Any way to make it stop at new line?

Comment: Further: the simple version works fine, the complex version grabs the following line up until `'` on the next line

Comment: I've made it less greedy bu using `[^']*?` instead of `[^']*`. I thought you'd be processing it line by line, in which case the original should work.